# add_filter(allowed_block_types) -> adding core/paragraph bugs Gutenberg editor

Tags: filters, block-editor

I'm facing a strange issue with the "core/paragraph" block :
An already-working "allowed_filter_types" (see code below), with core & custom blocks, starts bugging out the Gutenberg editor, once i add the 'core/paragraph' in the $allowed_blocks array.

**My problem :

The block-appender at the bottom of the editor disappears, so i can't easily add a new block anymore.**

The paragraph block itselft is working fine though.

I also have a custom container block, working fine.
But, in the same way, once i add "core/paragraph" in his allowed-blocks, the block-appender inside of it disappears as well.
Could anyone know where this could come from ?
(I'm building a theme from scratch, maybe i should call for this core/paragraph somewhere else first ? Didn't have to do so with the other core/blocks though.)
Thank you for reading, hope you can help !

**Here is the code :**
*For the add_filter :*

```
add_filter( "allowed_block_types", "filter_allowed_block_types", 10, 2 );
function filter_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks, $post ) {

   if( $post->post_type == "my_post_type" ) {
      $allowed_blocks = array(
         "core/heading",
         "core/image",
         "core/gallery",
         "core/video",

         "core/paragraph",

         'my-custom-container'
      );
   }
return $allowed_blocks;
}
```

*For my custom container :  (didn't add the attributes' stuff, working)*

```
edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {

   let allowedBlocks = [
      'core/heading',
      'core/paragraph',
      'core/image',
      'core/gallery',
      'core-embed/instagram',

      'core/video',
      'core-embed/youtube',
      'core-embed/vimeo'
   ];

   return([
      <div className={ type }>
         <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks = { allowedBlocks } />
      </div>
   ]);

},

save( { attributes } ) {
   return (
      <div className={ type }>
          <InnerBlocks.Content />
      </div>
   );
}
```